# Compare member of date dimension with constant

Tags: compare, constants, mdx, member

We have a problem to compare Date dimension members with some arbitrary date constant in mdx queries.

I want compare Date dimension members.

We take an arbitrary constant from user and need to do a filtering of some dimension comparing to that value but not knowing the exact values in the dimension, meaning the value doesn't have to belong to the member's list of the dimension.(because we don’t have all member in time dimension.)

our queries doesn't work correctly:

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Trade Cnt] } ON 0,
    bottomcount(FILTER([VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].[Reception Date],
    [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].Currentmember.MemberValue < '2009-08-10T00:00:00'),1) ON 1
FROM 
    [DV Present]
```

Comment: What's your date format? [VW Dim Customer Broker Branch].[Reception Date].&[2009-08-10T00:00:00]?

Comment: What does it return for you?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,That is.
my date format is:
[VW Dim Customer Broker Branc Firm].[Reception Date].&[2009-08-05T00:00:00]